# start cmake-gui with variables

Tags: variables, batch-file, command-line, cmake

I want to start cmake from a batch file with some variables preconfigured, like

```
cmake-gui.exe -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH="D:/Programmieren/C++/zlib/zlib-install/include" -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH="D:/Programmieren/C++/zlib/zlib-install/lib"
```

unfortunately, this just starts cmake-gui without any paths set.

The ultimate goal is to create a batch file, that can be run via context menu when I rightclick a `CMakeLists.txt` that creates two folders in the folder above the `CMakeLists.txt`:

- `{projectName}-build` and
- `{projectName}-install`

and then sets `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to the install folder and then I can just click configure, set some project specific stuff and then generate my VisualStudio solution in the build Folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the variable VAR_NAME inside the same batch script launching cmake-gui (e.g. through a 'set VAR_NAME=something' on Windows or export on Linux called before cmake-gui) you can retrieve it in the CMakeLists.txt using:

```
$ENV{VAR_NAME}
```

So you could define this variable and then you can use it to set internal CMake variables or to search paths of external libraries.

Comment: I would like to set the Paths for Libraries and Include Folders, so I can just use the `CMakeLists.txt` that is provided to me without changing it. Your approach would make me change code, that maybe does not belong to me and I would very much like to not do that.